# STORAGE [main] In File::open(), ::open for '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_user.js' failed with Permission denied

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, permissions, docker-compose

Here is my docker-compose file's container code. when it goes to volume part and have to add a user it shows error

1. `Error saving history file: FileOpenFailed: Unable to open() file /home/mongodb/.dbshell: No such file or directory`
2. `In File::open(), ::open for '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_user.js' failed with Permission denied
   failed to load: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_user.js`

   ```
   mongodb:
       image: mongo
       container_name: puc_mongodb
       restart: always
       ports:
         - "27018:27017"
       expose:
         - "27017"
       environment:
         - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
         - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=dummy
         - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=puc
       volumes:
         - "./docker_files/mongodb/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/"
   ```

**create_user.js code**

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "arbisoft",
    pwd: "dummy",
    roles: [ { role: "dbOwner", db: "puc" } ]
  }
)
```

Comment: check the permission on `create_user.js`

Comment: how to check the permission there?

Comment: file is not even opening

Comment: on your localhost `ls -l  /docker_files/mongodb/create_user.js`

Comment: this command shows this result 
**-rw------- 1 shahrukh shahrukh 111 Sep 19 11:16 ./docker_files/mongodb/create_user.js**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the permission on the file on your `host`:

```
chmod o+rw ./docker_files/mongodb/create_user.js
```

currently only you can read/write  the file.

Comment: i am using docker containers can't i put this line inside any part instead of manual enter this line??? can i put this line in my docker file???

Comment: that should runs on your host not the container

Comment: can't i put this in my docker file on first line?

Comment: You only need that once not every time you start the container since it is a volume

Comment: Thanks you soo much #LinPy